# Highlighting "current" navigation link when using template navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I'm inexperienced at coding and trying to build a pretty simple site with some HTML and CSS in Dreamweaver. I'd like my navigation menu to highlight the current page a viewer is looking at, and I've found different ways to do this. However, to make life easier as the site evolves, I've made the navigation menu an uneditable region of a template. I'm therefore finding myself unable to make the coding changes (e.g., giving a unique class to each link or a unique body id to each page) to each page that would seemingly allow me to highlight the current page link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this to detect a word in url:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

    $(document).ready(function($) { 
         if(window.location.href.indexOf("contact") >= 0){ 
              $(".contactLink").addClass("active"); 
         } 
    });

</script> 
<style> 
    .active { color: black; font-weight: bold } 
</style> 


<a href="../contact.html" class="contactLink">contact</a>
```

This could add a class to the menu item that has the word "contactLink" as a class.  So long as you have this js on all pages (put it in a file rather than hard coded on all pages) it will work.  If you copy the above code into a page called test.html the link is normal.  change the name to contact.html and it goes black..

Give each menu item a class, and then duplicate the code above for however many items you have.

There are more dynamic ways of doing it, but if you don't have millions of pages, is a nice easy way.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Like I said, I'm pretty inexperienced, so I'm trying to get this to work, but can't quite do it. Let me post step by step to see where I'm going wrong...

My jQuery....
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
    if(window.location.indexOf("contact") >= 0){
                 $(".contactLink").addClass("active");
            }
});</script>

My css...
<style>
.active { 
    color: black;
 font-weight: bold
}
</style>

My html...
<a href="../contact.html" class="contactLink">contact</a>

Comment: OK, this should be slightly easier to read...

My jQuery...
`<script> $(document).ready(function($) { if(window.location.indexOf("contact") >= 0){ $(".contactLink").addClass("active"); } });</script>`

My css...
`<style> .active { color: black; font-weight: bold } </style>`

My html...
`<a href="../contact.html" class="contactLink">contact</a>`

Comment: I've added one extra thing, and included jQuery as well if you hadn't added it... I will revise the above answer to include it all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with Dreamweaver template attributes which allow you to have editable tag attributes:
https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/defining-editable-tag-attributes-templates.html

While editing your template, if you put your cursor on the nav item class, you could then go to Modify > Templates > Make Attribute Editable.

Then, when editing the page based on the template, you'll be able to add an active class.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. For any other noobs, I found this video particularly helpful: http://layersmagazine.com/editable-attributes-in-dreamweaver-templates.html

Comment: Glad I could help!